# cant update a record with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I would like update a record in my controller. I tried with save or update_attributes, but it doesnt work.

My code is :

```
  @relation = Relation.where(:realtor_id => @message.realtor_id, :user_id => current_user.id)
  puts @relation.inspect
  @relation.save
```

`puts relation.inspect` bring me the good object but.
I got this message

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Relation:0x007fe6d6872fe8>):
```

I've the same problem with "update_attributes".

I 've 3 models : User , Realtor and Relation. I use "has_many :through" for create the link between User an Realtor through Relation.

My goal is to add `relation.status = "something"` before saving.
When i add `@relation.status = "test"`, i get :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `status=' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>):
i think, it's a stupid error, but i cant solve it :)
```

I'm not in User, Realtor or Message controller but in another controller (message controller)

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer...

I use :
  `@relation = Relation.where(:realtor_id => @message.realtor_id, :user_id => current_user.id).take`

instead of : 
 `@relation = Relation.where(:realtor_id => @message.realtor_id, :user_id => current_user.id)`

Answer (score 1):

```
@relation = Relation.find(params[:id])
@relation.users.create(current_user) #or build and then .save
```

Comment: Thank you but i doesnt work.

I 've 3 models : User , Realtor and Relation. 

I use "has many :through" for create the link between User an Realtor through Relation.

I dont understand why you use : "@relation.users.create(current_user)"

Comment: the same code just replace `Relation` with `Realtor` should work

Comment: it doesnt work, i use  @relation = Realtor.find(@message.realtor_id) and i got NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<User:0x007fe6d2eca818>):

I've update my question with more informations...

Comment: I'm busy now, I couls help you after ~ 10 hours, if you'll not solve the problem, we try to simulate the app on github. Just write if it needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some insight on why that is... if you don't already know now.

`.where()` responds with an array - every time.  Even if there is only 1 result, it's still in an array, so it's not an instance of your model.  `.find()` responds with an object.

So with `.where()` you can use take, or `.where(...).first -or- .take -or- [0]`.

With `.find(params[:id])`, it's going to be a bit more succinct, and just return the record you're looking for, or error if it doesn't it exist.  `.where()` won't error if it can't find what you're looking for.  That's something else to keep in mind.